connecting external hdd via usb3.0 to SATA IDE adapter
I've connected an old HDD using a USB3.0 to SATA IDE adapter. it appears in Disk Management as Disk 1. It's mapped to drive A however I can't access it from windows explorer. How do I access the device.

Drive A may still be a reserved letter (going back to old floppy disks). If you delete the drive letter assignment can you assign it a letter somewhere past D?
